# What is the best way to access a google drive folder with node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, drive

I have two options to do it, but I've been trying and I don't see a way.

The first option is to pass the credentials of the Google test account, and without asking for authorization (since you already have the credentials saved) you can access the folder (that is, use Google Drive simulating a login with node to access).

The other option I'm thinking about is to put the shared folder through a link and try to use a google drive web scraper to try to access the files in the folder, but I can't find an ideal scraper for this, I've only found [this one](https://github.com/leviwheatcroft/metalsmith-google-drive) that doesn't. I know if it works.

I have tried using the google developer console with the drive api but it requires an explicit login, when what I want is for it to automatically log in with the credentials given in the code.

Comment: Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis?